# Add more ressources to Server service on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, samba, service, cifs

I'm trying to configure Service service on Windows 7, to add more ressources to it.

In our infrastructure there is a Linux server, which has mounted partitions from a Windows 7 machine. Partitions are mounted through cifs filesystem.

When there is a complex request for multiple files in one time, Windows macine doesn't serve all files.

Also sometimes in such situations, Server service is falling down, and we must restart it.

If there is a way to configure Server service on Windows, to give it more RAM, priority etc ?

Comment: Purchase a server. You can't run the 24 hours of Le Mans on a donkey. Use the product appropriate to the need. If it's outside of your budget then you'll have to live within the limitations of what your budget affords.

Comment: The problem, what we have multiple workstations in our infrastructure, which uses such model, and currently it's out of question to make such massive OS upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are limitations on Windows client operating systems. These are hard-coded and cannot be circumvented. If you need more than 10 concurrent SMB/CIFS connections to a Windows machine, then you need to purchase Windows Server.

Comment: Wow ! That's really impressive.
We couldn't afford Windows Server for this mission. I'll try to find a solution or by queuing of requests, or by replacing native Server service of Windows 7 by something external (need to check, if it exists).

Comment: Instead of hacking away at the core of the OS and leaving yourself in an unsupported state, why don't you see if there are any Linux or BSD alternatives available that would suit your needs?

Comment: Completly agree. Personnaly, I'm using Ubuntu and it works very well in described model. The problem is, what we need Windows specific programms on the machine in question, and these programms needs lots of ressources and are not compatible with Windows emulators.

Comment: So, instead of mounting a Windows volume on the Linux server and hitting these restrictions, why don't you mount a Linux volume on the Windows box?

Comment: That's a good idea, will do it. It sounds like a most easy solution in the case of existing of such Windows 7 limitations.